# Can't replace value in table cell with inline jquery editing

Tags: jquery, inline

it is a while that I'm stuck on this issue: I would like to make a sort of excel spreadsheet (well, just few columns of a table), but I'm not able to set the new value.

Here is the (not) working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zgnm3a0d/4/).

Steps:

- double click on yellow cell
- fill in the new value
- blur or press enter key

The old value is still there... I don't know why this is happening, I thought I had to handle this with `clone()` but the result was the same.

Note: I have to do this because I don't want to overwrite/lose the `€`, `%`, `£` sign. I guess this can also be achieved with css only, but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it right, except for a small error when putting everything pack into `$td`.

Replace this code:

```
$(prev_html).find('span').text( new_val );
$td.html( prev_html );
```

With this:

```
$td.html(prev_html);
$td.find('span').text(new_val);
```

Doing `$(prev_html)` creates DOM objects in memory based on `prev_html`, and then you manipulate those DOM objects. But that does not change `prev_html`, which is what you seemed to expect.

What I did is put `prev_html` back into `$td` (*first new line*) and then proceed by manipulating `$td` (*second new line*).

See the new [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/13mwLa5s/1/).

*And as a Snippet:*

```js
$('.can-edit-this').on('dblclick', function(){
 var $td = $(this).closest('td');
 $td.addClass('editing');
 prev_html = $td.html();
 
 var $input = $('<input class="form-control" type="text" id="can-edit-this-field" name="" value="'+$(prev_html).text()+'" style="table-layout: fixed;" />');
 
 $td.html($input);
 $input.focus();
 
 $input.on('blur', function(){
  var new_val = $(this).val();
  $td.html(prev_html);
    $td.find('span').text( new_val );
  $td.removeClass('editing');
  prev_html='';
 });
 
 $input.on('keypress', function(e){
  if(e.which == 13){
   $(this).trigger('blur');
  }
 });
});
```

```css
table td {width: 50px !important}
.can-edit-this {background-color: #fcefa1;}
.can-edit-this.editing {padding:0 !important}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td class="can-edit-this"><span>123</span>€</td>
    <td class="can-edit-this"><span>234</span>%</td>
    <td class="can-edit-this"><span>345</span>£</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td class="can-edit-this"><span>123</span>€</td>
    <td class="can-edit-this"><span>234</span>%</td>
    <td class="can-edit-this"><span>345</span>£</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td class="can-edit-this"><span>123</span>€</td>
    <td class="can-edit-this"><span>234</span>%</td>
    <td class="can-edit-this"><span>345</span>£</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 4</td>
    <td class="can-edit-this"><span>123</span>€</td>
    <td class="can-edit-this"><span>234</span>%</td>
    <td class="can-edit-this"><span>345</span>£</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 5</td>
    <td class="can-edit-this"><span>123</span>€</td>
    <td class="can-edit-this"><span>234</span>%</td>
    <td class="can-edit-this"><span>345</span>£</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I knew it was something easy :) Thank you very much!! Can you explain what are you referring to when you say "$(prev_html) did not make sense", because since `.html()` returns a string, I have to make it an object to search for an element inside it